# array. accessing 0xFFFFFFFF element

Tags: c, arrays, memory, stack

I have code that is similar to the below.

```
    int foo (unsigned int a)
    {

    struct tid{
        int id;
        char abd[8];
        };
    int ret = 0;
    struct tid arr[256];

    ret = arr[a];
    ...

    }
```

The value of a passed to foo is 0xFFFFFFFF. Now, since we are accessing a memory location outside of the stack, I would assume the system would fault, but it is not.
I would like to know a direction in which I could look to find out how this could work.
The machine under consideration is a MIPS 4K, with 32 bit addressing and 256 MB of RAM. I am cross compiling the code on a x86 PC using gcc.

Comment: With 32 bit addressing, accessing index 0xFFFFFFFF is equivalent to accessing index -1, which is likely legal

Answer (score 4):

> Now, since we are accessing a memory location outside of the stack, I would assume the system would fault, but it is not.

Writing outside the bounds of memory you have allocated on the stack is [undefined behaviour](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). Invoking this undefined behaviour usually (but not always) results in a segfault. **However, you can't be *sure* that a segfault will happen.**

The wikipedia link explains it quite nicely:

> When an instance of undefined behavior occurs, so far as the language specification is concerned anything could happen, maybe nothing at all.

So, in this case, you could get a segfault, the program could abort, or sometimes it could just run fine. Or, anything. There is no way of guaranteeing the result.

> I would like to know a direction in which I could look to find out how this could work.

I'm not sure what you're asking here. Could you clarify what you mean by "work"? What do you want this program to do?